# Should numpy threading be disabled with multiprocessing for the highest performance?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've recently run across the knowledge, due to a related error and work around, that internally, numpy uses it's own threading / multicore processing, even with a 'single' python thread/process.

When writing 'high performance' code, which makes heavy use of python's 'multiprocessing' module to speed up calculations, is it best to disable all of numpy's internal threading, in order so that no 'thrashing' occurs? (more cpu threads calculating than actual cores, so inefficient context switching)

If so, how would this be best accomplished? I saw some older threads recommending an approach like this at the very beginning of the program:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```

Is this still the most comprehensive method?

Comment: This sets vars of many common BLAS/LAPACK libraries for which you probably only have one. That said, this smells to me like trying to optimize too soon in the process... I wouldn't go and launch 100's of processes, but modern systems have 1000's of threads at any given time, and the OS is pretty good at juggling them efficiently. I'm not going to say it won't help at all, but it's not likely to be a huge perf gain... Better yet: build a semi-complete example, and profile with various #'s of processes. It's always better to profile than guess what will make things fast or slow.

Comment: for example on my system right now (with background stuff, and chrome open) I have almost 2500 threads! `import psutil; print(sum(p.num_threads() for p in psutil.process_iter()))`

Comment: @Aaron this is separate. Threads are fine when they are idle most of the time. My calculations will run and demand 100% CPU time.

Comment: I am aware of the concept of thrashing a cpu with threads, but what I am saying is that it's not usually a huge perf hit unless you have a truly ridiculous number of cpu bound threads. The things you are asking about are going to be heavily OS and even hardware dependent, so the only realistic answer is to build your application, then test it (profile). You should figure out what BLAS/LAPACK you have, and then go looking for its specific documentation on tuning. You could even look up if any compilers do better or worse for building it, but again: hardware & OS dependent means you have to test